# No Space left on device - Debian

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, disk-usage, size

when Im new to linux and try to run this below code

```
apt-get -f install
```

getting below error:

[image]

Checking the available space

```
df
```

Tho output [image]

How to increase the available space in /usr path?

Comment: would you mind pasting your output as text rather than images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using LVM to manage your `/usr` partition, you probably should check the [LVM-documentation](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html).

to extend the partition (to e.g. 10GB)

```
# lvextend -L10G /dev/mapper/vg0-usr
```

after that you can extend the filesystem. this is fs-specific, under ext3 use:

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg0-usr
```

you *might* have to reboot between the two commands, and it would be safer to do an *offline* fsresize (that is: unmount `/usr` before running `resize2fs`; which might be hard on a running system; use a live-CD in such a case (e.g. the Debian installer CD has a "Rescue" option for such cases)

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to reboot after an lvextend. And AFAIK online expand is pretty safe.